# synchronization with multi threading in java effects the utiliztion time. How to solve this

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am learning java concepts...i just want to understand the synchronization with multi threading concept once. When we are using multi threading, we generally go for synchronization in order to align the transactions in sync.

But by adding this u end up with more utilisation of time. How to make application in sync and to use multi threading as well...are their any concepts in java which solve this...

Comment: You gain something and you lose something !

Comment: Using object locks is the most heavy-weight way of protecting shared resources. Look at the java.concurrent package. It contains more fine grained constructs that incur less overhead.

Comment: I can understand that this is difficult material to grasp and that you'd want help trying to understand it, but the question as it is asked now comes dangerously close to going to a math forum and stating "Calculus is difficult, can someone explain it?" :) The general response will be book recommendations, and lo and behold - what is happening in this thread?

Answer (score 5):

You're thinking of [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law), which implies that from a big-O standpoint, yes, synchronized sections completely defeat the point of multithreading.

The point is to keep synchronized sections as small as possible so they don't become bottlenecks at the scale you're actually anticipating. Or to use other concurrency patterns that simulate synchronization but do not require a lock. Read [*Java: Concurrency in Practice*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Comment: Interesting that we both post the same hint to read a good book.

Answer (score 2):

Buy yourself [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.de/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) , it really describes everything about Java and multithreading (and what can totally go wrong). It i written by one of the Lead Architects of Java back in the Sun days and the programmer of the java.util.concurrent framework.